# How is a zeta converter different from a buck-boost converter?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

Both the topologies have the same output equation, but zeta appears to be better. Why's that?

Comment: Define better. What differences have you found?

Comment: Ah, let me see: Zeta is good because: (1) its series cap decouples input and output well, (2) it can either step up or down. On the other hand, Zeta is bad because: (3) architecture is complicated to implement, especially for low power apps.